# ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.general_log' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, centos, upgrade, general-log

After mysql upgrade I'm getting this error on my Centos box when I tried to enable `general_log`. Any idea?

`SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';`

`ERROR 1146 (42S02) : Table 'mysql.general_log' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created that missing table and worked for me.

Login to mysql console

`use mysql;`

```
CREATE TABLE general_log(
event_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
user_host mediumtext NOT NULL,
thread_id int(11) NOT NULL,
server_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
command_type varchar(64) NOT NULL,
argument mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you find yourself in this situation then you problem have done a MySQL upgrade and incorrectly carried over the datadir (e.g. /usr/local/var/mysql) to the new installation.

So the accepted solution above will solve your immediate problem but it also indicates that you might have other problems with your MySQL install as well.

Answer (score 1):

just an Addition to **Harikrishnan's** answer!
I had to alter the fields type to work from me as MYSQL could not write to table so:

1. if general_log is enabled, turn it off `SET GLOBAL general_log= 0;`
2. Create table
   `USE mysql;
   CREATE TABLE mysql.general_log(
   event_time TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
   user_host MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
   thread_id BIGINT(21)UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   server_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   command_type VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   argument MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='General log';`
3. reenable logging `SET GLOBAL general_log= 1;`
4. view log `SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log;`